# I added ellipsis for long text in CSS but it is showing just

Tags: css, wordpress

I added ellipsis for the long text in CSS but it is showing just **...**
No Text is showing.

For example, say this is my long text: **“I Got a Degree but Ended Up Selling Charcoal To Survive”**

Now after adding the ellipsis, I was **expecting** my text to be something like this: **“I Got a Degree but End...**
See screenshot below:
[image]

But after adding the ellipsis, I saw just **...**
See screenshot below:
[image]

See my CSS code below:

```
    .breadcrumb, .rank-math-breadcrumb { 
   
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    margin-bottom: 24px !important;
    margin-bottom: 24px !important;
     display:inline-block !important;
    width: calc(80%); 
}

.breadcrumb, .rank-math-breadcrumb p { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: I inspected the [web page](https://allschool.com.ng/i-got-a-degree-but-ended-up-selling-charcoal-to-survive-young-lady-reveals/) on chrome with (Right click → inspect). I am using WordPress

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/uTv18x

Comment: You can try it like this: `.breadcrumb span[itemprop="name"] {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 24ch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}` The width you can adjust based on characters or px.

Comment: @m4n0, I like how the text is truncated. But the problem is that your breadcrumbs are vertical. I want horizontal.

Comment: I can't even find `.rank-math-breadcrumb` class on that page...

Comment: @Diraph Your breadcrumbs? It's already vertical: https://nimb.ws/CqxsFT

Comment: Just add `.breadcrumb { display: flex; gap: 1em; }` for it to be horizontal.

Comment: @m4n0 By horizontal line, this is what I mean (https://ibb.co/XxH6g87)

Comment: @Tony, the class is on the page. Just inspect the breadcrumb

Comment: Please go read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) The answer is No - you are supposed to present a proper [mre] that illustrates the issue, directly inside your question.

Comment: @CBroe, I didn't quite get you. The links provided in the question are screenshots to help understand my question. 

I also added the code.

Finally, I indicated that I am working with Wordpress.  

How else do you want my question illustrated?

Comment: Why not, what is there not to understand about what is explained under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/1427878 ? Do not send us to external sites to try and check on what your problem is - but provide the _minimal_ code that is necessary to re-create it, directly inside your question.

Comment: @CBroe, as I said, the link is just an image screenshot. If I know the code to recreate my problem, I won't even be asking the question. I need the code to fix the problem.

Comment: Please add markup to your question. Thanks.

Comment: This here is supposed to be a Q&A site, the work and effort we are investing on _your_ behalf here, should ideally be able to help future readers gain some knowledge as well. That won't be possible, if you just refer us to a site that won't even show the problem any more, once it got fixed.  _"If I know the code to recreate my problem, I won't even be asking the question."_ - _reducing_ this is still your responsibility. Often times you might even be able to find the reason/solution yourself, while you are dojng that work of reducing this to the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tell us rather little.

Comment: @CBroe, 1) I have removed all links from the question and added a screenshot image instead. 2) I said I am working with WORDPRESS. and I only want to edit the CSS of a class. I hope I am not wrong to assume that you know what WordPress is and how it works?

Comment: And I hope that you know that there are a multitude of different _themes_ for WordPress, all of which could be producing wildly different HTML ...? Plus, that does not change _anything_ about the reasoning, why we want you to show a proper [mre] directly inside your question.

Comment: I have edited the post again. I really don't know what else to do here. If you can help me, please do. Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).